# C++ CreateWindowEx returns NULL

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to set up a simple window using C++, but my call to `CreateWindowEx` returns `NULL`. Most of the code I'm using comes from the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the MSDN website. Nothing that I've tried has worked, and any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
//Include the windows header
#include <Windows.h>

//Forward declaration of the WndProc function
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

//Main entry point
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    //Window class name
    const wchar_t windowName[] = L"Window Class";

    //Set up window class
    WNDCLASS wnd;
    wnd.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wnd.hInstance = hInstance;
    wnd.lpszClassName = windowName;

    //Register window class
    RegisterClass(&wnd);

    //Create window
    //! This returns NULL
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        windowName,
        L"Windows Programming",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
        );

    //Simple check to see if window creation failed
    if(hWnd == NULL) {
            //Pause
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }

    //Show the window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    //Main message loop
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

//WndProc function
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hDc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            FillRect(hDc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            return 0;
        }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I see no `GetLastError` in your code, but yet you're here. I notice a couple aspects of filling out your `WNDCLASS` are missing, though.

Comment: Use `GetLastError`  to get the error code, and post it.

Comment: Did RegisterClass succeed? What did it return.

Comment: You need to check the results of `RegisterClass`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe `GetLastError` isn't even mentioned anywhere on that example page. Typical Microsoft. At least it *is* mentioned on all of the pages for the actual functions.

Comment: You probably want to make sure you initialize the entire `WNDCLASS` structure before registering it.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, Indeed, though even zeroing it out will leave something missing, or at least (seeing as how it's not included in the example) make a difference, as it did for another problem posted here.

Comment: I have tried it just to move this question forward. After the call to RegisterClass, GetLastError() returns error 87 : "ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER".

Comment: @chris:  The example does zero out the entire structure, but this code does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that the sample from MSDN zeros out all the fields of the WNDCLASS before setting the ones it cares about.

```
WNDCLASS wnd = { };  // from MSDN example
```

The empty braces are a C and C++ shorthand for initializing the entire structure to 0.  It's also common to write this as `{ 0 }`, which technically is slightly different but has the same net effect.

In your code, you dropped the initialization:

```
WNDCLASS wnd;  // your code
```

Thus you are likely getting some garbage value in one of the other important fields, like `cbClsExtra` or `cbWndExtra`, that rendered the class impossible to register.  Since the class wasn't registered, you couldn't create a window of that class.

Answer (score 8):

I have made your code work. Basically what I do when using the WNDCLASS (or WNDCLASSEX) structure is use all parameters to be sure not to miss something.

```
//Include the windows header
#include <Windows.h>

//Forward declaration of the WndProc function
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

//Main entry point
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    //Window class name
    const wchar_t windowName[] = L"Window Class";

    //Set up window class
    WNDCLASS wnd;
    wnd.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wnd.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wnd.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wnd.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wnd.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wnd.style = 0;
    wnd.hbrBackground = 0;
    wnd.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wnd.hInstance = hInstance;
    wnd.lpszClassName = windowName;

    //Register window class
    RegisterClass(&wnd);

    //Create window
    //! This returns NULL
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        windowName,
        L"Windows Programming",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
        );

    //Simple check to see if window creation failed
    if(hWnd == NULL) {
            //Pause
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }

    //Show the window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    //Main message loop
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

//WndProc function
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hDc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            FillRect(hDc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            return 0;
        }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: if a switch statement returns, no break is needed.

Comment: Indeed. Don't think it deserves a -1 for this. The answer is still right. I will fix that.

Comment: Inadvertent mouse click, my apologies, touch pad..again, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem. I call [CreateWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window) always returns NULL.

That is because different messages need different return values.

for example: [WM_NCCREATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccreate)

> If an application processes this message, it should return **TRUE** to **continue creation** of the window. If the application returns **FALSE**, the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function will **return a NULL handle**.

you can use [DefWindowProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-defwindowprocw) to help.

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWindow, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWindow);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWindow, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // add this
    }
    return 0;
}
```