# C winapi hwnd returning null

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have tried everything to find the problem, but down below is my code and `hwnd` returns `NULL` when I run the program. What might be the reasons? The code seems fine. The program was working fine for a long while until 15 mins ago. I cut this part of the source code and ran it again but it still return NULL. This is that part that I cut.

```
#include <windows.h>
#define IDI_MYICON 103

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

//font

/*hFont = CreateFont(40,0,0,0,700,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH,TEXT("a"));
hFontIpAdres = CreateFont(25,0,0,0,700,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH,TEXT("a"));
hFontKurbanSecimi = CreateFont(30,0,0,0,700,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH,TEXT("a"));
*/
  WNDCLASSEX wc;
  HWND hwnd;
  MSG msg;

  char *windowClassName = "class1";
  printf("%s\n", windowClassName);

  wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wc.style         = 0;
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
  wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
  wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
  wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON));
  wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
  wc.lpszMenuName  =  NULL;//MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MYMENU);
  wc.lpszClassName =  windowClassName;
  wc.hIconSm       =  NULL;//(HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);

  if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
  {
    printf("window registration failed\n");
  }

   printf("%s\n", windowClassName);
  hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, windowClassName,"TTr",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
      );
  if(hwnd == NULL){
    printf("could not create window hwnd %d\n", GetLastError());
  }
  ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
  UpdateWindow(hwnd);

  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0){
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ CreateWindowEx returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661912/c-createwindowex-returns-null)

Comment: *"The code seems fine."* - A compiler warning is hardly ever a reason to believe, that code is fine. You cannot declare a return type, and then not return anything from a function. Any introductory book on C explains that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WndProc()` function doesn't return anything.  `CreateWindowEx()` will actually call the window proc with some creation-based messages.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You are referring to WM_CREATE message

Comment: @Asesh that is one of many messages that `CreateWindow/Ex()` sends to the window procedure before exiting.

Comment: @Asesh: Given the code in the question, there will be no `WM_CREATE` message. Window creation terminates before sending that message. The messages sent during window creation are [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx).